# How to set slanting shaded box and also hyphen box using tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox, shading

Good day! Hi everyone, here I am using tcolorbox package I have two types of box styles, one is slanted shaded type and another one is without slant and hyphen border around it. I highlighted box one in "RED" color and box two style in "GREEN" color. Please suggest how to resolve this.

MWE:
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\RequirePackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\newenvironment{Boxtwo}{\begin{tcolorbox}[bicolor,colback=white,colbacklower=white,
colframe=black,tikznode lower={inner sep=2pt,draw=red,fill=yellow}]
}{\end{tcolorbox}}



\begin{document}

\begin{Boxtwo}%[WORKED E.G. 1.1]
\begin{itemize}
\item Solving number sentences with multiple operations with or without brackets
\item Writing number sentences to describe problem situations
\item Checking solutions by substitution
\item Using properties of operations on whole numbers to simplify number sentences
\end{itemize}
\end{Boxtwo}

\begin{Boxtwo}%[WORKED E.G. 1.1]
\subsection{Addition}
A patient asks you how many medicines they need to swallow to take all their morning medicines. They have the following medicines to take:
\begin{itemize}
\item 500 mg paracetamol (2 capsules)
\item 40 mg frusemide (1 tablet)
\item 62.5 mcg digoxin (2 tablets)
\end{itemize}
A patient asks you how many medicines they need to swallow to take all their morning medicines. They have the following medicines to take:
\end{Boxtwo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The hyphen border is possible with the `borderline` options of `tcolorbox`, but the slanting is a little bit tedious -- both however are examples of bad design, in my point of view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to adjust margins, spacing, colors, font, etc., but you have something to start

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[
    enhanced, 
    frame hidden,
    colback=cyan!10,
    top=3mm,
    overlay={%
        \draw[rounded corners, red, dashed, ultra thick] (frame.north west) rectangle (frame.south east);
        \node[font=\Huge\sffamily\bfseries, text=blue, anchor=west, rotate=5] at ([xshift=5mm] frame.north west) {Some title};}, 
    ]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[
    enhanced, 
    frame hidden,
    colback=white,
    top=3mm,
    underlay={%
        \fill[orange!30, rounded corners] (frame.north west)--([shift={(1mm,1mm)}]frame.north east)--([shift={(3mm,-3mm)}]frame.south east) -- ([shift={(0mm,-1mm)}]frame.south west) -- cycle;
        \fill[white, rounded corners] (interior.north west) rectangle (interior.south east);},
    overlay={%
        \node[font=\Huge\sffamily\bfseries, text=blue, anchor=west, rotate=5] at ([xshift=5mm] frame.north west) {Some title};}, 
    ]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ignasi, Your answer really fulfill my requirement.